# Kernel source on precise-armhf v3.6.2-x3 on a BeagleBoard XM

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, beagleboard

I have a BeagleBoard XM on which I installed Ubuntu from [rcn-ee](http://rcn-ee.net/deb/rootfs/precise/). Now, I'm looking to install the 8192cu driver because I can't get WiFi to work with the kernel driver. However, the makefile for the driver needs a path to the kernel source, which I can't find.

I think the kernel is in /lib/modules/3.6.2-x3/kernel, but that doesn't seem to have the source. How/where can I get the source for this in order to install the driver?

Note: If I give 
`KSRC := /lib/modules/3.6.2-x3/`
I get
`No rule to make target 'modules'. Stop.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build drivers you should only need the kernel headers.  There is a thread on the [beagleboard group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/beagleboard/zaFBY77Xt4U) that explains where to find the source and headers (note that it is fairly old, so you may need to adjust for your build).

This [post](http://lakm.us/logit/2012/01/compile-usb-serial-modem-using-option-c-ubuntu-on-beagleboard-xm/) also looks relevant

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure out the solution by cross-compiling the headers from the RobertCNelson stable-kernel package. I modified version.sh to get the kernel I needed.